# the color doesn't fit into the progress bar at the begining

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a timer progress bar,
I used progress tag in HTML, and found that when the timer starts, the color doesn't fit into the progress bar like pic 1 [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNNTn.png) ; While turn normal few seconds later like pic 2. [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueIP8.png)

```
 function startProgress(seconds) {
 const startTime = Date.now()
 const progressValue = progress.value
 const progressStartValue = progressValue
 const totalTime = ((seconds * 1000)/(100 - progressStartValue))*100
 
 progressId = setInterval(()=>{
  let now = Date.now()
  
  let runProgress = progressStartValue + ((now - startTime) / totalTime)*100
  console.log(runProgress)
  renderProgressBar(runProgress)
   
   
   if(runProgress > 100) {
     clearInterval(progressId)
     progress.value = 0
   }
 }, 100)
}
```